# Arrays Splice Pop Shift Read

Tags: javascript, arrays, push, splice

I create an array like so

```
var membersList = $('#chatbox_members' , avacweb_chat.doc.body).find('li');
var onlineUsers = [];
var offLineUsers = [];
for(var i =0;i<membersList.length;i++){
    var name = $(membersList[i]).text().replace("@","");
    onlineUsers.push(name);
}
alert(onlineUsers);
```

`listedUsers` would come out something like so `[Mr.EasyBB,Tonight,Tomorrow,Gone];`

Question is if I use a two for loops one outside a setInterval and one inside to compare-

```
var membersList = $('#chatbox_members' , _chat.doc.body).find('li');
var onlineUsers = [];
var offLineUsers= [];
for(var i =0;i<membersList.length;i++){
    var name = $(membersList[i]).text().replace("@","");
    onlineUsers.push(name);
}
var int = setInterval(function() {
    var newMember = ('#chatbox_members' , _chat.doc.body).find('li');
    for(var i =0;i<newMember.length;i++){
        var name = $(newMember[i]).text().replace("@","");
        offLineUsers.push(name);
    }
```

Which then would get:

```
onlineUsers = [Mr.EasyBB,Tonight,Tomorrow,Gone];
offLineUsers =  [Mr.EasyBB,Tonight];
```

So to get the offline users I want to basically replace `onlineUsers` with `offLineUsers` which then should return `Tomorrow,Gone` . Though I know that an object doesn't have the function to replace so how would I go about this?

I don't think the splice function would work since you need to have parameters, and pop or shift are beginning and end of array.

Comment: You could iterate through the array,check if the onlineUsers contains elements found in offLineUsers , and if they do exist , remove those elements.

Comment: Hmm harsha, can you show me an example of iterating an array? Please and thank you as that would be my first iteration

Comment: Your for-loops were iterations.

Comment: Oh thats an iteration :/ lol. Well let me see if I can figure this out then I guess

Comment: Did you get a solution to your problem? If so, consider sharing it with us.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for(var i = 0 ; i < offLineUsers.length ; i++)
{
    for(var j = 0 ; j < onlineUsers.length ; j++)
    {
        if(onlineUsers[j] == offLineUsers[i])
        {
            onlineUsers.splice(j,1);
        }
    }
}
```

Try this snippet.

Comment: Not sure what I did wrong here http://jsbin.com/umimid/1/edit maybe because the elements don't exist ? but yeah wouldn't the if statement be !== ?

Comment: Why are you pushing members who are actually online to offline array.I am talking about this.
`var newMember = ('#chatbox_members', avacweb_chat.doc.body).find('li');
    for(var i =0;i<newMember.length;i++)
 {
        var name = $(newMember[i]).text().replace("@","");
        offLineUsers.push(name);
    }`

Answer (score 0):

This should do what you are looking for on a modern browser, using [array.filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)

```
var onlineUsers = ["Mr.EasyBB", "Tonight", "Tomorrow", "Gone"];
var offLineUsers = ["Mr.EasyBB", "Tonight"];

function discord(online, offline) {
    return online.filter(function (element) {
        return offline.indexOf(element) === -1;
    });
}

console.log(discord(onlineUsers, offLineUsers));
```

Output

```
["Tomorrow", "Gone"]
```

On [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Xotic750/mC6CN/)

If you want the difference regardless of the order of attributes passed to the function then you could do this.

```
var onlineUsers = ["Mr.EasyBB", "Tonight", "Tomorrow", "Gone"];
var offLineUsers = ["Mr.EasyBB", "Tonight"];

function difference(array1, array2) {
    var a = array1.filter(function (element) {
        return array2.indexOf(element) === -1;
    });

    var b = array2.filter(function (element) {
        return array1.indexOf(element) === -1;
    });

    return a.concat(b);
}

console.log(difference(onlineUsers, offLineUsers));
console.log(difference(offLineUsers, onlineUsers));
```

Output

```
["Tomorrow", "Gone"] 
["Tomorrow", "Gone"]
```

On [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Xotic750/gVyXU/)

Answer (score 0):

If I have understand well, maybe that helps:

```
function bus_dup() {
for(var i = 0; i < offLineUsers.length; i++) {
    onLineUsers.splice(onLineUsers.indexOf(offLineUsers[i]),1);
}
offLineUsers = [];
}
```